# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2\big(\ln(x\cot^{-1}(x))$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2\big(\ln(x\cot^{-1}(x))$$

I tried using the Series Expansion of the $\ln(x)$ but then got stuck in between. I also tried using the L'Hopital but the expression got quickly messy. 
After applying L'Hopital for the first time, I got

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-x^3}{2}\bigg(\frac{-x}{1+x^2} + \cot^{-1}x\bigg)$$

The expression is still in the undefined form. Unless the question maker wants to torture the *problem solver*, this method would not be the way to go.

I have got no other clue for solving this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think that here $\cot^{-1}(x)$ means $\text{arccot}(x)=\arctan(1/x)$ which is positive for $x>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$\text{arccot}{(x)}=\arctan{\left(\frac1x\right)}=\frac1x-\frac1{3x^3}+o\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)$$
as $x\to\infty$. Also note that as $y\to0$ we have
$$\ln{(1+y)}=y+o(y)$$
Hence our limit is simply
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\ln{(x\text{arccot}{(x)})}
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\ln{(x(1/x-1/(3x^3)+o(1/x^3)))}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\ln{(1-1/(3x^2)+o(1/x^2))}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2(-1/(3x^2)+o(1/x^2))\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}(-1/3+o(1))\\
&=-\frac13\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that as $x\to +\infty$,
$$\cot^{-1}(x)=\arctan(1/x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+o(1/x^3).$$
Hence, from your work, 
$$\frac{-x^3}{2}\bigg(\frac{-x}{1+x^2} + \cot^{-1}(x)\bigg)=
\frac{-x^3}{2}\bigg(-\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} + \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+o(1/x^3)\bigg)\\
=\frac{-x^3}{2}\bigg(-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+o(1/x^3)\bigg)\to -\frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

one more method:
put $x=\frac{1}{t}$
so now its

$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t^2}ln(\frac{1}{t}tan^-1(t))$
now use expansion of lnx. But we know this-

$ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}$
we only need till here (chill out )
for lnx, replace x with "x-1"
so now u have your expansion of
$ln(x)=(x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}$
Now, lets get back to limit.

$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t^2}ln(\frac{1}{t}tan^-1(t))$
As term inside ln is $\frac{1}{t}tan^-1(t)$
by the expansion we have:
(using only 1st term)
$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t^2}ln(\frac{1}{t}tan^-1(t)-1)$

simplifying,

$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t^3}ln(\frac{1}{t})-\frac{1}{t^2}$

simplify further

$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{tan^-1(t)-t}{t^3}$
Use L-hospital now.
as there is $\frac{0}{0}$ form.
After 1st diffrentiation, put t=0, and u will get answer $\frac{-1}{3}$
Upvote If u like.. Thank U